# zend framework 3 Select tag validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I am getting the error:
The input was not found in the haystack
After form post. Please see the selection tag code lines below:

```
// Add "roles" field
    $this->add([            
        'type'  => 'select',
        'name' => 'roles',
        'attributes' => [
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
            'options'=>$this->role_desc,
             'inarrayvalidator' => false, 
             'class'=>'form-control'
        ],
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Role(s)',


        ],


    ]); 




  // Add input for "roles" field
    $inputFilter->add([
            'class'    => ArrayInput::class,
            'name'     => 'roles',
            'required' => true,
            'haystack'=>$this->role_ids,
            'filters'  => [                    
                ['name' => 'ToInt'],
            ],                
            'validators' => [
                ['name'=>'GreaterThan', 'options'=>['min'=>1]],
                 ['name'=>'InArray', 'options'=>['haystack'=>$this-
                       >role_ids]]


            ],
        ]);
```

The InArray seems to be validating well, lm just no sure what is bringing up the exception. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually , your issue is similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805448/zf2-how-do-i-use-inarray-validator-to-validate-multiselect-form-element)

To solve this, change your validators definition to:

```
'validators' => [
          ['name'=>'GreaterThan', 'options'=>['min'=>1]],
          [
                'name' => 'Explode',
                'options' => array(
                      'validator' => [
                           'name'=>'InArray',
                           'options'=> [
                                'haystack'=>$this->role_ids
                           ]
                       ]
                )
          ]
],
```

Unfortunately, I do not think there is a "cleaner" way to do this.
   Alternately, Maybe you could use the **MultiCheckbox**.

Comment: Hi @Jannes,Im getting The input was not found in the haystack again , using the above

Comment: Can you add your post data dump?

Comment: Hi @Jannes,Please see below:                                                                         array(8) { ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" ["username"]=> string(26) "mutyambiziathene@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(6) "nyarai" ["mobile"]=> string(10) "0798578123" ["email_add"]=> string(26) "mutyambiziathene@gmail.com" ["category"]=> string(5) "mycat" ["motivation"]=> string(13) "my motivation" ["roles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } }

Comment: Hm, is "$this->role_ids" an array of integers? Can you post the dump of "$this->role_desc" and "$this->role_ids"?

Comment: $this->role_desc:                                                                            
array(5) { [5]=> string(13) "administrator" [4]=> string(6) "author" [2]=> string(6) "editor" [3]=> string(9) "publisher" [1]=> string(6) "viewer" }                                                                                                              $this->role_ids:                                                                                   array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "3" [4]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: I am not sure what is causing your issue, you can try to change 'options' => ['label' => 'Role(s)','disable_inarray_validator' => true,].  Are you sure it is the roles that is causing this error? Maybe it is category or motivation.

Comment: thats the only select tag l have. That's why l think its the roles tag

Comment: try the "disable_inarray_validator" option, all else look good.